# Aligning an image in a div to the right to sit behind text in another div

Tags: css

I am trying to accomplish this (PNG mockup):
[image]

By trying this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM8J5/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="traintext">The East London Line part of the London Overground line that runs north to south through the East End, Docklands and South areas of London.</div>
    <div class="trainimage"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Unit_378150_at_Whitechapel.jpg/300px-Unit_378150_at_Whitechapel.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.traintext {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.trainimage {

}
```

But I'm not sure what I need to do to get **.trainimage** and **.traintext** in the right place.

Comment: Your PNG mockup isn't linked

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, it is the image below the text I have added.

Comment: Oops, my proxy must be blocking it :P

Comment: The address I can see is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2xKaH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to absolutely position the text; thus removing it from the flow and placing it over the floated `img` element. [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KTqGq/)

```
.traintext {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    position:absolute;
}

.trainimage {
    float:right;
}
```

You shouldn't have any problems with this approach; given that the parent `.container` has defined dimensions (meaning it won't collapse because of the floated/absolutely positioned elements)